# C++ data structure to perform indexed list

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary, stl

I am looking for the most efficient data structure to maintain an indexed list. You can easily view it interms of a STL map :

```
std::map<int,std::vector<int> > eff_ds;
```

I am using this as an example because I am currently using this setup. The operations that I would like to perform are :

- Insert values based on key : similar to eff_ds[key].push_back(..);
- Print the contents of the data structure in terms of each key.

I am also trying to use an unordered map and a forward list,

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::forward_list<int> > eff_ds;
```

Is this the best I could do in terms of time if I use C++ or are there other options ?

**UPDATE**:

I can do insertion either way - front/back as long as I do the same for all the keys. To make my problem more clear, consider the following:

At each iteration of my algorithm, I am going to have an external block give me a (key,value) - both of which are single integers - pair as an output. Of course, I will have to insert this value to the corresponding key. Also, at different iterations, the same key might be returned with different values. At the end my output data(written to a file) should look something like this:

```
k1: v1 v2 v3 v4
k2: v5 v6 v7
k3: v8
.
.
.
kn: vm
```

The number of these iterations are pretty large ~1m.

Comment: Either of those sound like good solutions. Why are they not sufficient? Do you have particular requirements that make them invalid? Are your datasets large enough for it to matter? Which particular operation are you most concerned about (lookup? deletion? insertion?)

Comment: I am concerned only with insertion from the back/front, that doesn't matter. My datasets are quite large, in the sense that the number of possible keys can exceed 1million but the number of items per node is over the order of hundreds. You can think of it as a big graph but with sparse connections. I am interested in only adding the edges and printing the contents of the graph in terms of each edge. Hope this makes it clear. I would just like to know if there are smarter ways of doing this with C++.

Comment: Using an unordered_map will render single-element access extremely fast but also sequential access extremely slow. If you need to print out all the associated values with a key and all the keys in the map I would go for an std::map. Otherwise if you only access keys singularly go for unordered_map. Since you're already considering keys I won't be talking about adjacency lists/vectors.

Comment: @MarcoA. "unordered_map...sequentual access extremely slow... I would go for std::map"... what gave you that idea?  Given a reasonable hash function and the default max_load_factor of 1, you'll likely have 10-55% empty buckets - contiguous in memory and only pointer sized so very cache-friendly to skip over.  Compared to a `vector` storing incrementing key values it's slow to iterate (and index) due to chasing pointers around, but `std::map` has that same weakness anyway.

Comment: Do you need to consider duplicate values added to a key? ie. suppose your algorithm produces (5, 7) and then later this combination occurs again, would you want key 5 to have (7,7) or just (7)?\

Comment: Good point, the key should have (7,7), although the duplicate itself would not occur at all in my problem. You can safely assume that each key will be associated only with unique values.

Comment: @TonyD http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/. Specific cases are different from the general case.

Comment: @MarcoA. that's not a good site to trust for anything... here's a quick illustrative benchmark on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/64sgeM) - `unordered_map` iteration was consistently more than 3 times faster than `std::map`.

Comment: @TonyD I wouldn't call that a good sample for any case, especially with 1KK elements. OP wants an integer key and it would be better to just experiment, but with different keys and more elements map outperforms umap on my system (O3)

Comment: @MarcoA. share your benchmark or it's FUD... ;-P.

Comment: If you can run more than 10k elements on coliru or ideone I'll be happy to do it :D Otherwise you should just take my word on 19k / 22k (and I didn't go further). Anyway I still think OP should benchmark his code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two dimensions to your problem:

1. What is the best container to use where you want to be able to look up the items in the container using a numeric key, with a large number of keys, and the keys are sparse

   A numeric key might lend itself to a vector for this, however if the keys are sparsely populated that would waste a lot of memory.

   Assuming you do not want to iterate through the keys in order (which you did not state as a requirement), then an unordered_map might be the best bet.
2. What is the best container for a list of numbers, allowing for insertion at either end and the ability to retrieve the list of numbers in order (the value type of the outer map)

   The answer to this will depend on how frequently you want to insert elements at the front. If that is commonly occurring then you might want to consider a forward_list. If you are mainly inserting on the end then a vector would be lower overhead.

Based on your updated question, since you can limit yourself to adding the values to the end of the lists, and since you are not concerned with duplicate entries in the lists, I would recommend using `std::unordered_map<int,vector<int> >`

Comment: @Swami have updated to take your updates into account, although the  recommendation does not change much!